# i get undefined method error when i use IsAdmin middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

***//here is my route***

```
Route::get('/works', function () {
    $works=Work::all();
    return view('works',compact('works')); })->middleware('IsAdmin');
});
```

***here is my IsAdmin function in User Model***

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','user_role','user_id','role_id');
}

public function IsRole(){
    return $this->roles; 
}
```

***And this is my IsAdmin middleware***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   $user=Auth::user();

   if($user->IsRole()->name=='Administrator'){

        return true;

    }
}
```

why it give me undefined method error?

Comment: This question is not clear. But did you register your middleware?

Comment: yes i register middleware but it don't know isRole() function in User Model.  Full Error: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Your middleware should `return $next($request)` instead of `true`.

Comment: i changed IsRole function to -------                 public function IsRole(){


        foreach($this->roles as $role){

        }
          return $this->role; 
             
    }                                                                          
 now it give me "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object".

Comment: @qayaxan_eyvazli Could you please send me the result `print($user->IsRole(), true);`?

Answer (score -1):

do you register your middleware inside `app/Kernel.php` into `$routeMiddleware` array.
Should be something like that

```
protected $routeMiddleware = ['check.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\YourClass::class]
```

Comment: I just joined this post. The post owner has corrected "undefined method" error into "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance" error. Please update your post again. Good luck.